# Web application code for validation

Tags: python, web-applications

Hi I have a problem with the web application. It always give a form back. I code like this:

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form method="post">
what is your birthday
<br>

<label>Month
 <input name="text" name="month">
</label>

<label>Day
 <input name="text" name="day">
 </label>

 <label>Year
 <input name="text" name="year">
 </label>

 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

months = ['January',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']

def valid_day(day):
    if day and day.isdigit():
        day = int(day)
        if day < 32 and day > 0:
                        return day

def valid_month(month):
    if(month):
        month = month.capitalize()
        if month in months:
                        return month

def valid_year(year):
    if year and year.isdigit():     
        year = int(year)
        if year < 2020 and year > 1880:
                        return year

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)


    def post(self):
    user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
    user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
    user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

    if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
        self.response.out.write(form)
    else:
        self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

But even I give a right input, it still give back the form. Could anyone help me with this? I can not check what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted you don't specify the action attribute of your form so when you click submit, the form is not being sent anywhere. In order to give you a full answer, I will need to see your server side code (if it exists) that handles form submission 
for example

```
<form method="POST" action="/path_to_server_code">
```

then your server should listen to POST request at the URL specified in the action and you should process the form at that location

for example:

```
@app.route('/path_to_server_code') 
def process_form():
    # do something with the form
```

Comment: Hi, really tanks for your help. I am running my web application on my localhost:8080 via google appengine. This is my whole code.

Comment: So did I answer your question or are you asking me another question?
glad I can help